# Homology of Derivations of a dgca algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-modules

Let $(A,d)$ be a differential graded commutative and associative algebra.
A derivation on $A$ is a linear endomorphism $L: A \to A$, that satsfies
$L(ab)= L(a)b+ aL(b)$. More general a derivation of degree $n$ is a linear
map $L: A \to A[n]$, (where $(A[n])_k:=A_{k+n}$) such that 
$L(ab)= L(a)b + (-1)^{n|a|}aL(b)$.

The graded vector space $Der(A)$ of all derivations (of any degree $n$), i.e
$\oplus_n Der(A)_n$ with
$Der(A)_n:=\{L:A \to A[n]\;|\;L\;linear\;and\;L(a)b + (-1)^{n|a|}aL(b)\}$
has itself a differential $d_{Der}$ defined by the equation
$d_{Der}L=L\circ d \pm d\circ L$ (I'm not sure about the sign right now)

To summerize, we have two chain complexes $(A,d)$ and $(Der(A),d_{Der})$ and the question
is:

Is there any relation between the homology $H(A)$ and the homology $H(Der(A))$?